# Mongo - sort after $project doesnt work

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregation-framework, project

I have three collections - articles, categories and users. Each article can have author and subauthor and I would like to list currentUser data - it can be username or nickname, becuase users can use two different types. I have aggregation for that and it works fine, but $sort using currentUser projected column is invalid - yep, it's sort "something" but not sure what, because "aaa" is in the beginning, then is "Test" and in the end is... "Second Test". Should be in the middle.

I use $project and $cond inside it to get - first, specific author using current user id, then, username or nickname. Results are ok, only sorting is broken.

BTW. Is it better way to get only one record from lookup instead of using $arrayElemAt?

```
[ { '$match': <MY CONDITIONS> },
  { '$lookup': 
     { from: 'categories',
       localField: 'category',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'categories' } },
  { '$lookup': 
     { from: 'users',
       localField: 'author',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'author' } },
  { '$lookup': 
     { from: 'users',
       localField: 'subauthor',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'subauthor' } },
  { '$project': 
    { _id: 1,
       name: 1,
       status: 1,
       updatedAt: 1,
       currentUser: {
          '$cond': {
            'if': { '$eq': [ userId, '$creator'] },
            'then': {
              '$cond': {
                'if': { '$eq': [ '', {'$arrayElemAt': ['$author.username', 0]} ] },
                'then': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$author.nickname', 0]},
                'else': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$author.username', 0]}
              }
            },
            'else': {
              '$cond': {
                'if': { '$eq': [ '', {'$arrayElemAt': ['$subauthor.username', 0]} ] },
                'then': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$subauthor.nickname', 0]},
                'else': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$subauthor.username', 0]}
              }
            }
          }
        },
    } 
  },
  { '$sort': { currentUser: 1 } }
]
```

Comment: What does this pipeline output without the `$sort`?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution - it was because missing collation. Added with locale en_US / strength = 1 and it works fine now.